# run login form unnatended on windows service

Tags: c#, windows, service, authentication

I have a service that should connect to a video management server that does not provide soap Access or other command line login options, so I have to use their login form for getting information. The problem is that I need to create a Windows service that gets the info every now and then.  Is it possible?
I'm using c#. 
Login is done via Windows login form provided by SDK that only Works on Windows not web.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since they do not provide any sort of service, you would need to basically read in and parse the HTML returned from their server. This is sort of a broad question, but you can at least look in the direction of using  `HttpWebRequest` and related classes. You would basically be performing a series of `GET` and/or `POST` requests to their web server and parsing the returned HTML for the information you need. You can run into issues with this approach if they end up changing their HTML depending upon how you are parsing it.

Comment: Hi.  Based on your response I have to add that they provide a Windows based login form

Comment: You would need to create a credential object that you pass with your request, take a look at Microsofts MSDN entry: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.credentials%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks.  I will try that.